# linq2db after update to 5.0 / 'Invalid configuration. Configuration string is not provided

Tags: linq2db

I've updated to linq2db 5.0 and when I try to execute it I got the error ': 'Invalid configuration. Configuration string is not provided.'
'

Here's my configuration

```cs
public static void RegisterLinq2DbConnection(this IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
    //using LinqToDB.AspNet
    builder.Services.AddLinqToDBContext<AppDataConnection>((provider, options) =>
    {
        options
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
            .UseDefaultLogging(provider);

        return options;
    });

    builder.Services.AddScoped<ITTGRepository, TTGRepository>();
}
```

and here's the AppConnection

```cs
public class AppDataConnection : DataConnection
{
    public AppDataConnection(DataOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

But in the config step I got the connection string valorized.. any suggestion? I've followed the update guide on linq2db page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`DataOptions` are immutable and you have to return newly created options when configuring context.

```cs
//using LinqToDB.AspNet
builder.Services.AddLinqToDBContext<AppDataConnection>((provider, options) =>
{
    return options
        .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
        .UseDefaultLogging(provider);
});
```